# Crystal Reports - A Subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

The following function returns the "A subscript must be between 1 and size of array"- error when run in Crystal Reports 2013. I have tried to figure this out, but not sure how to fix this error.

```
Whileprintingrecords;
stringvar array sMessage := split({Inventory.MessageText},",");
If UBound(sMessage ) > 0 then
(
   Trim(sMessage [1]) & Chr(13) & Trim(sMessage [2]);
)
```

I also tried this...

```
Whileprintingrecords;
stringvar array sMessage := split({Inventory.MessageText},",");

Numbervar Array numbers;
Redim numbers[Ubound(sMessage)];

If UBound(numbers) > 0 then
(
   Trim(sMessage [1]) & Chr(13) & Trim(sMessage [2]);
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic867.html

```
Examples

The following examples are applicable to Crystal syntax:
 [100,233,466,998][3]
Returns 466; 466 is the third element in the array.

LNAME [1]
Returns "S", where LNAME = "Smith".

Postal [6]
Returns "V", where Postal Code = "T5A 9V2" (the space between A and 9 counts as an element).

{customer.POSTAL CODE} [5 to 7]
Returns "9V2", where Postal Code = "T5A 9V2".

{file.ITEMNUMBER} [4 to 5]
Returns "40", where ItemNumber is A1/4020/B10.
```